# Laravel TokenMismatchException with Curl Post

Tags: laravel, token, mismatch

Can someone help with this Token problem?
I think i set the token correct, in the header and in the input post field

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");


$url = 'http://------My url------/';

foreach ($_POST as $k => $v){
    $fields[$k] = $v;
}

// build the urlencoded data
$postvars = http_build_query($fields);

// open connection
$ch = curl_init();

$headers[] = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN:'.$fields['_token'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

// execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
// close connection
curl_close($ch)
```

;

[image]

Comment: What are you doing here? You really need to provide more information and code. That code you posted here isn't really making any sense unless you know all your code.

Comment: What i first wanted was to do a Ajax post crossdomain. But then i got a tokenmismatch. So i touth i send the ajax post to the laravel/public/ folder where i have a ajax.php that gets the post, and makes a post to the new route. (so the second post is not crossdomain) but still i get a token error